# How to "stretch" a form group in a container (Bootstrap 4)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've tried playing around with the paddings, but it didn't solve the issue.

The idea is to stretch these fields from where they are all the way to the right.

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/m7c2z31t/11/#&togetherjs=wvKEoPg2aQ) and this is how it looks VS what it should look like.

[image]

```css
 

  input[type='text'],
  .txtarea {
    margin-bottom: 3px;

  }

  .form-group input, select{
    height: 36px;
    padding-left: 03px;
    padding-right: 03px;
  }
  
  .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 2px !important;
}

  .padding-0 {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }



  label {
    color: #292727;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: right;
  }

  label[for='notes'] {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
  }

  .container-fluid {
    max-width: 99%;
  }
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
  </head>
  <div class="container-fluid px-5" id="container1">
    <div class="row d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center">
      <div class="col">
        <img src=class="header__logo-img" alt="Some Hidden Logo" itemprop="logo" width="237" height="90">
      </div>
      <div id="unitSpot" style="display: none;">Fabric</div>
      <div class="col">
        <form id="headerForm">
          <div class="form-group row" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
            <label for="select" class="col-4 col-form-label">Order:</label>
            <div class="col-4">
              <select id="selectOrderPo" name="select" required="required" class="custom-select" onchange="loadSuppliersForPoFromSS(this);resetPage()">
                <option value="TTL-220218" selected="">TTL-2131231</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row" style="display: flex;justify-content: flex-end;">
            <label for="fabricPo" class="col-4 col-form-label">PO:</label>
            <div class="col-4">
              <input id="fabricPo" name="fabricPo" type="text" required="required" value="" class="form-control" disabled="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
            <label for="poDate" class="col-4 col-form-label">PO Date:</label>
            <div class="col-4">
              <input id="poDate" name="poDate" type="date" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy" onchange="generateShipDate(getLeadTime())">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
            <label for="leadTime" class="col-4 col-form-label">Lead Time:</label>
            <div class="col-4">
              <input id="leadTime" name="leadTime" type="number" class="form-control" onchange="generateShipDate(this)" min="0" max="180">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
            <label for="text3" class="col-4 col-form-label">Ship Date:</label>
            <div class="col-4">
              <input id="shipDate" name="shipDate" type="text" class="form-control" disabled="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `px-5` on your container which is specifying `3rem` of padding on the left and right. Step one would be to remove this because `container-fluid` already has a left and right padding of `15px`.

Then, when you work your way down the elements you'll notice some more default `padding` on all your `col-4`'s. You can use `pr-0` to target only the `padding-right` to be `0`.

```css
input[type='text'],
.txtarea {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.form-group input,
select {
  height: 36px;
  padding-left: 03px;
  padding-right: 03px;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 2px !important;
}

.padding-0 {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

label {
  color: #292727;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: right;
}

label[for='notes'] {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}

.container-fluid {
  max-width: 99%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="container-fluid" id="container1">
  <div class="row d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      <img src=class="header__logo-img" alt="Some Hidden Logo" itemprop="logo" width="237" height="90">
    </div>
    <div id="unitSpot" style="display: none;">Fabric</div>
    <div class="col">
      <form id="headerForm">
        <div class="form-group row" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
          <label for="select" class="col-4 col-form-label">Order:</label>
          <div class="col-4 pr-0">
            <select id="selectOrderPo" name="select" required="required" class="custom-select" onchange="loadSuppliersForPoFromSS(this);resetPage()">
              <option value="TTL-220218" selected="">TTL-2131231</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row" style="display: flex;justify-content: flex-end;">
          <label for="fabricPo" class="col-4 col-form-label">PO:</label>
          <div class="col-4 pr-0">
            <input id="fabricPo" name="fabricPo" type="text" required="required" value="" class="form-control" disabled="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
          <label for="poDate" class="col-4 col-form-label">PO Date:</label>
          <div class="col-4 pr-0">
            <input id="poDate" name="poDate" type="date" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy" onchange="generateShipDate(getLeadTime())">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
          <label for="leadTime" class="col-4 col-form-label">Lead Time:</label>
          <div class="col-4 pr-0">
            <input id="leadTime" name="leadTime" type="number" class="form-control" onchange="generateShipDate(this)" min="0" max="180">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
          <label for="text3" class="col-4 col-form-label">Ship Date:</label>
          <div class="col-4 pr-0">
            <input id="shipDate" name="shipDate" type="text" class="form-control" disabled="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Right on! So much going on here for a beginner to assimilate - your help is inspiring. Thanks!